# Why my AlarmManager is not correct?

Tags: android

I tried to write an alarm application, it works well when i choose time after time of system. But when i choose another time before time of system. it alarms immediately, i can't understand :( Help me pls. I use TimepickerDialog to choose time.
Here is choose time code.(by click textview)

```
time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //savePrefs();
            int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    get_hour = selectedHour;
                    get_min = selectedMinute;
                    millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                    time.setText( selectedHour + " : " + selectedMinute);
                }
            }, hour, minute, true);
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Set Alarm");
            onoff_alarm.setChecked(false);
            mTimePicker.show();

        }
    });
```

and here is my onoff togglebutton

```
onoff_alarm.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(onoff_alarm.isChecked()){
                my_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm on");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Alarm On :  " + get_hour + " h " + get_min + " m ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, my_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pending_intent);
            }
            else {
                my_intent.putExtra("extra","alarm off");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm Off !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                alarmManager.cancel(pending_intent);
                sendBroadcast(my_intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please try to describe the exact problem.

Comment: By *But when i choose another time before time of system* -- do you mean *currentSystemTime - <some_value>*?

Comment: Example my problem: now My Phone is 8h10m, i choose from timepickerdialog is  8h12m ( after 8h10m), my code is works exactly when my phone got 8h12m, app ringtones and pushes notification. 
But when I choose time is 8h08 or anytime before my phone time. App immediatly ringtone and push notification without wait for nextday ( i think that ).
Sorry about my poor English.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of alarm manager is to schedule some task after certain time in the future. Why would you want to trigger an alarm in the past,ie, before system time?
I think the code is working fine.
Setting the time before system time triggers your alarm immediately because the time has already pass.